# phpinfo() file blank setting up LAMP

Tags: php, lamp

so I am trying to set up a LAMP server on my Ubuntu machine.

I have been following this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

And I got to the point where I am trying to access test.php (I named it info.php) with http://localhost/info.php and it is just creating a blank page in Firefox. The file is in /var/www/html/. I can view source and see the code in Firefox but it is not actually running it.

The code is

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

pretty simple. I tried setting display_errors to on in the conf file but it does not seem to change anything. Other than it is the default config after running

```
$ sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

Thank you

Edit: This might have been ignored, but in case anyone comes across it and needs it:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.0
```

restart, it might have an error on restart, in which case

```
sudo a2dismod mpm_event

sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork
```

Then restart, fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

This might have been ignored, but in case anyone comes across it and needs it:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.0
```

restart, it might have an error on restart, in which case

```
sudo a2dismod mpm_event

sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork
```

Then restart, fixed it for me